# CGAL alpha shape python simple example went wrong?

Tags: python, cgal

I wish to obain the alpha shape using CGAL.

@sloriot provides [an extremely relevant script](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/cgal-python/test/Alpha_shapes_2/test_alpha_shape_2.py?view=markup&root=cgal-python) and after my customization:

```
from sys import *
path.append("../../cgal_package")

from CGAL.Alpha_shapes_2 import *
from CGAL.Triangulations_2 import Delaunay_triangulation_2
from CGAL.Kernel import *

from random import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

import constants

def Point_2_str(self):
    return "Point_2"+str((self.x(), self.y()))
# now we turn it into a member function
Point_2.__str__ = Point_2_str


def show_alpha_values(AS):
    print "Alpha spectrum"
    for alpha_value in AS.alpha:
        print alpha_value


def read_points(file):
    result = []
    dataFile = open(file, 'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(dataFile):
        coordinateList = [float(x) for x in line.strip().split()]
        for j in range(0, len(coordinateList), 2):
            result.append(Point_2(coordinateList[j], coordinateList[j+1]))
    dataFile.close()
    return result


def getAlphaShape():  
    L =[]
    verbose = True
    list_of_points = read_points(constants.PROJECT_PATH + '\\data\\clusters.txt')

    a = Alpha_shape_2()
    a.make_alpha_shape(list_of_points)
    a.set_mode(Alpha_shape_2.Mode.REGULARIZED)
    a.set_alpha(1000)
    alpha_shape_edges = []
    alpha_shape_vertices = []
    for it in a.alpha_shape_edges:
        alpha_shape_edges.append(a.segment(it))
    for it in a.alpha_shape_vertices:
        alpha_shape_vertices.append(it)

    _showAlphaShape(list_of_points, alpha_shape_vertices)

    print "alpha_shape_edges"   
    print len(alpha_shape_edges)
    print "alpha_shape_vertices"    
    print len(alpha_shape_vertices)
    print "Optimal alpha: " 
    print a.find_optimal_alpha(2).next()


def _showAlphaShape(points, vertices):
    fig = plt.figure()
    axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]) # left, bottom, width, height (range 0 to 1)
    axes.axis('equal')
    axes.set_xlabel(r'$x (m)$')
    axes.set_ylabel(r'$y (m)$')
    axes.set_title(r'$\alpha$-shape of clusters')
    # draw cluster points
    x = [pt.x() for pt in points]
    y = [pt.y() for pt in points]
    axes.scatter(x, y, s=1)
    # draw alpha shape
    for i in range(len(vertices)-1):
        x1 = vertices[i].point()[0]
        x2 = vertices[i+1].point()[0]
        y1 = vertices[i].point()[1]
        y2 = vertices[i+1].point()[1]
        axes.plot([[x1, x2], [y1, y2]], color='b')
    fontP = FontProperties()
    fontP.set_size('7')
    axes.legend(loc=3, prop=fontP)
    fig.savefig(constants.PROJECT_PATH + '\\data\\1.svg')
```

**Once I run it, I get**

[image]

The blue part is obviously **not** the alpha-shape. **Where went wrong?**

Comment: What documentation page are you reading? You need to translate the C++ examples to python. [Here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html#title4) is one. FYI, as written on the website of cgal-python, this package is no longer maintained and now [cgal-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) is the recommended alternative.

Comment: @sloriot  I have the same question here. I simply need an alpha-shape for a set of points, that is all. So not many requirements, just the cgal-python package will be sufficient. Could you please kindly show a working example of my purpose? Simply the alpha shape of a random point set. Thanks a lot! This will also help others, since the documentation is really shabby.

Comment: @sloriot  Thank you so so much! This seems **extremely** relevant! However, for some unknown reasons, once I run the snippet, my python.exe directly hangs and dies. Any idea>

Comment: Did you compile the bindings yourself?

Comment: @sloriot  No, but I indeed have installed the package, which means that I have no problems importing the modules. It is just when I run the whole snippet, it dies. I am really sorry but I am a newbie. How may I do that please?

Comment: @sloriot  I have solved that issue, but you can see the alpha shape I obtained is incorrect. Please see the updated question. I will be extremely grateful, if you can help! :D

Comment: @sloriot Problem identified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946150/cgal-triangulations-2-vertex-point-causes-python-to-die Please kindly help! I have been doing this for days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See from [your detailed question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946150/cgal-triangulations-2-vertex-point-causes-python-to-die). I highly suspect it is due to the mismatch between your CGAL and your Python package.

Comment: Although did not point out a solution, at least I have a direction to work on. No other answers are there. So.